# Rails 3 advanced query

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi I'm new to rails 3 and can't figure out how to create an advanced query.

In the view I need to show a list of documents, each with its associated packetType, grouped by subject for a user.

a user can have many subjects, a subject can have many documents and a packetType can have many documents

There are four tables:

```
users
subjects
documents
packet_types
```

so here are my model associations

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :subjects

end

class Subject < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :user
has_many :documents

end

class Document < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :subject
    belongs_to :packetType

end

class PacketType < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :documents

end
```

In the controller how do I call this query? and in the view how do I display the subject name, the documents' name that belong to each subject and the packet_type name that belongs to each document for the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would think your query would look something like this:

```
@subjects = current_user.subjects.includes(:documents => :packetType)
```

That query will load all the users subjects, and then eager load all documents belonging to the subject, and the packetType for the document. So then in your view it would look something like this (assuming haml):

```
- @subjects.each do |subject|
  = subject.name
  - subject.documents.each do |document|
    = document.name
    = document.packetType.name
```

Since all your database queries were done in the one line in the controller, the view just needs to spin through all the data you just loaded.

Comment: i'm new to rails... what do you mean by (assuming haml)? what would the view look like without haml?

Comment: It's one choice of templating language you can use in rails. Another one would be ERB.